# Как подключить портативную runtime-библиотеку Windows для PHP CLI

Tags: php, windows, dll, runtime

Работаю над маленьким приложением, которое должны скачивать пользователи и которое включает в себя php-файл и бинарную версию интерпретатора PHP для Windows. Все это запаковано в одну zip-папку и для запуска такого локального мини-сервера (PHP CLI) как известно достаточно распаковать папку на любом диске, добавить путь к бинарам в переменную PATH, а потом в командой строке перейти в папку и выполнить

```
php -S localhost:80
```

Но как известно для работы PHP на Windows нужна также соответственная runtime-библиотека. Например для последней PHP 7.3 нужна VC CRT 14 (Visual Studio 2015). Хотелось бы запаковать ее тоже в свой zip, но как "портативную" т.е. без необходимости запускать какие то инсталяторы и если возможно даже без копирования в `C:/Windows/System32` Т.е. чтобы просто распаковали одну единственную zip-папку на любом диске, запустили cmd-команду и все сразу работает без лишних телодвижений (на usb-флешке не нужно, только любой хард диск).

На странице http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.requirements.php прочитал что можно как то собрать все инсталлированные DLL-файлы. Как это сделать? Может есть где то готовый список? (интересует именно VC 14 для PHP 7.3, в крайнем случае VC 11 для PHP 5.6)

Можно ли их потом как то "подключить" к бинарной версии PHP без инсталляции и даже без копирования в System32 и если да то как?

Имел ли кто нибудь опыт в подобном?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается достаточно просто скачать с Интернета файл [vcruntime140.dll](https://www.dll4free.com/vcruntime140.dll.html) и вставить его в папку PHP 7.3 чтобы PHP CLI работало на Windows. Не нужно ничего устанавливать и даже копировать в папку `Windows/System32`